# How to use nested conditional operators in EL to display String value

Tags: jsf, nested, el, conditional-operator

I want to use conditional operator in EL to display string value in place of integer value, when I used with two conditions it works, but with more than two conditions, I had error in EL.

work :

```
<h:outputText value="#{item.status == 'ACTIVATION_BEING_PROCESSED' ? 'OK' : 'KO'}"/>
```

didn't work :

```
 <h:outputText value="#{item.status == 1 ? 'ACTIVATION_OK': 
                        item.status == 0 ? 'ACTIVATION_KO' :
                        item.status == -1 ? 'UNDEFINED':
                        item.status == 2 ? 'ACTIVATION_TO_BE_PROCESSED' :
                        item.status == 99 ? 'ACTIVATION_BEING_PROCESSED' :
                        item.status == 98 ? 'ASSOCIATED':
                        item.status == 4 ? 'EN_COURS_GMD':
                        item.status == 12 ? 'KO_GMD' : '' }"/>
```

I had this error :

```
 org.apache.el.parser.ParseException: Encountered " "?" "? "" at line 1, 
  column 61.
  Was expecting one of:
   "}" ...
    "." ...
   "[" ...
   ">" ...
   "gt" ...
"<" ...
"lt" ...
">=" ...
"ge" ...
"<=" ...
"le" ...
"==" ...
"eq" ...
"!=" ...
"ne" ...
"&&" ...
"and" ...
"||" ...
"or" ...
"*" ...
"+" ...
"-" ...
"/" ...
"div" ...
"%" ...
"mod" ...
```

Comment: *"I had error in EL."* You forgot to include the error in the question. It usually represents the answer already.

Comment: @BalusC updated

Comment: OK, thus you're using Apache EL (which version?) and that one didn't expect a `?` character located at the 61th character of the expression. You've put quite some whitespace and newlines here and there, but I guess it's referring to the `?` one after `item.status == 0`. Most probably the expression is from that point on too ambiguous for the specific Apache EL version being used in order to properly parse it (perhaps it was expecting the `0` being some sort of condition). You could at most try to make it clearer to Apache EL by putting the parenthesis `( )` around every conditional statement.

Comment: @BalusC how can i know the version of Apache EL ?

Comment: I would create a bean method that performs this logic. It is way more easier to code in java than in el.